# Mostrar valores en array desde campo form

Tags: php, array, formularios

Tengo una serie de valores en un array llamado $arrayvali, los cuales quiero enviar a través de un campo oculto llamado rg[ps], en un form mediante post, en un principio no he incluido lo de enctype dentro del form porque no se si esto influye o no, creo que eso más bien es para temas de envio de subida de imágenes pero bueno, no se si hay o no que incluirlo, el caso es que si los valores que tengo en el array son 1,2,3 lo que quería es que cuando se envié el formulario mediante post pues que se muestren esos valores, solo sería eso, pero no hay manera, no se por qué siempre me sale la palabara Array, entonces ese es el objetivobasicamente, heprobado incluso a poner el campo rg[ps] como rg[ps][] o incluso cambiarel nombre a rg solo o a rg[], la verdad traté de hace rmuchas cosas y ni modo, en fin os dejo el ejemplo y espero me podaís ayudar, gracias

```
<?php
if($_POST['send']=="ok")
{
foreach($_POST['rg'] as $key=>$val)
{
echo $val;
}
}   
?>




<form action="" name="format" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<?php
$arrayvali=array("casa","puerta","mesa");
?>
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" name="rg[ps]" value="<?php echo $arrayvali;?>">
<input type="submit" name="sender" value="sends">
</form>
```

Comment: Para mostrar un array no se hace un `echo`, se hace un `var_dump`

Comment: Yo no estoy mostrando un array estoy enviándolo mediante formulario o post, si quisiera mostrarlo antes de enviarlo mediante post pues haría un loop y ese no es el propósito

Comment: Lo que quiero es enviar el array mediante el formulario

Comment: No estás mostrando un array ¿¿?? Entonces que dice la primera linea de la publicación ?? `Tengo una serie de valores en un array llamado $arrayvali...`

Comment: ¿A dónde quieres mostrar esos valores luego de enviarlos?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es pasar todo el array en un solo campo sin recorrerlo, Debes **Serializar** el array  o convertirlo a **Json**

**Convertirlo a Json**

```html
<?php 
$arrayvali= json_encode(array("casa","puerta","mesa"));
?>

<form action="" name="format" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" name="rg" value="<?=$arrayvali?>">
<input type="submit" name="sender" value="sends">
</form>
```

Para obtener el valor en el post

```html
if($_POST['send']=="ok")
  #Este para objeto
    //$valorenviado = json_decode($_POST["rg"]);
  #Este para array asociativo
    $valorenviado = json_decode($_POST["rg"],true);
    
    
  var_dump($valorenviado);

{
```

**Serializandolo**

```html
<?php 
$arrayvali= serialize(array("casa","puerta","mesa"));
?>

<form action="" name="format" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
<input type="hidden" name="rg" value="<?=$arrayvali?>">
<input type="submit" name="sender" value="sends">
</form>
```

Para obtener el valor en el post

```html
if($_POST['send']=="ok")

  #Este para array asociativo
    $valorenviado = unserialize($_POST["rg"]);
   
  var_dump($valorenviado);

{
```

**Si lo que quieres es pasar  cada valor del array en un campo por separado.**

```html
<?php
$arrayvali= json_encode(array("casa","puerta","mesa"));
$campos = "";
foreach($arrayvali as $key => $value){
  $campos .= "<input type='hidden' name='rg[]' value='$value'>";
}
?>

<form action="" name="format" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
<?=$campos?>
<input type="submit" name="sender" value="sends">
</form>
```

Para obtener el valor en el POST

```html
if($_POST['send']=="ok")
  var_dump($_POST["rg"]);
{
```

Comment: De 10 Gracias !

Answer (score 0):

Si al enviar el formulario buscar obtener en la variable `$_POST['rg']` un arreglo con los valor del arreglo `$arrayvali`, entonces lo que podrías hacer es recorer el arreglo `$arrayvali` y crear un `<input name="rg[]"` para cada valor.

#### Ejemplo:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send']) && $_POST['send'] == "ok") {
  foreach ($_POST['rg'] as $key => $val) {
    echo $val;
  }
}
?>

<form action="" name="format" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
  <?php
  $arrayvali = array("casa", "puerta", "mesa");
  foreach ($arrayvali as $val) {
  ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="rg[]" value="<?php echo $val; ?>">
  <?php
  }
  ?>
  <input type="submit" name="sender" value="sends">
</form>
```